# How to make a screenshot of a < div > , and within that there is a div tag < iframe>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, screenshot

I've used various frameworks ( html2Image , iframe2image , feedback.js ... ) but without success. Does anyone have any idea of how to generate an image of a < div > with the  tag within the page body ?

Comment: If the iframe comes from another origin, you simply can't without modifying the browser (or proxying the iframe). See [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Indeed, this is a rather critical security feature of browsers. Imagine how scary it would be if I could load up your bank/insurance/mortgage/etc. sites in an iFrame and take screenshots!

Comment: I found a solution. I had to implement a javascript function that makes the screen shot on the server side , after the capture he sends that result to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4912092/4749156). Niklas provided solutions with [HTML2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), examples are [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)

Comment: It does not work with Feedback.js when they have a < iframe> tag.
The iframe disappears !